# Unable to start or stop niginx using ansible

Tags: ansible

Am unable to start or stop niginx using ansible.

The yml file looks like this,

```
---
- hosts: loadbalancer
  become: true
  tasks:
   - name: install nginx
     apt: name=nginx state=present update_cache=yes

   - name: ensure nginx is installed
     service: 
        name: nginx 
        state: stopped
```

And am using ansible-playbook 2.5.1, funny thing is the install command works and the second task also returns that a change was performed but does'nt start or stop nginx.

Output i get,

> PLAY [loadbalancer]
>
> ---
>
> TASK [Gathering Facts]
>   ******************************************************************************** ok: [172.17.0.3]
>
> TASK [install nginx]
>   ******************************************************************************** ok: [172.17.0.3]
>
> TASK [ensure nginx is installed]
>   ****************************************************************************** changed: [172.17.0.3]
>
> PLAY RECAP
>
> ---
>
> 172.17.0.3                 : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0

Any explanation and solution helps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `changed: [172.17.0.3]` message means that the service was in a started state. In fact, when installing nginx, with your play, the default status is started so if you do:

```
   - name: install nginx
     apt: name=nginx state=present update_cache=yes
```

You will get:

```
systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2018-05-13 09:00:00 UTC; 38s ago
```

That means that when running:

```
   - name: ensure nginx is installed
     service: 
        name: nginx 
        state: stopped
```

You will stop the service (Changed for Ansible):

```
TASK [ensure nginx is installed] *****************************************************************************************************
changed: [ubuntu-1]
```

Checking the service, it is stopped:

```
systemctl status mginx
Unit mginx.service could not be found.
root@ubuntu-1:/home/vagrant# systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2018-05-13 09:01:28 UTC; 12s ago
```

Besides all of this explanation, I recommend installing Ansible 2.5.2 as 2.5.1 has serious bugs with lists.

Comment: Hi @imjoseangel , thanks for the reply. Nginx doesn't start when i use "state: started" , but its not the case with apache2 or mysql, but works when i use command module and provide "service nginx restart". Maybe i should upgrade the ansible version?

Comment: I fully recommend the upgrade. I have tested with NGinx and Ubuntu 17 and it works fine.

Comment: Using the latest ansible helped me resolve this issue. Thanks